# Class or interface Event could not be loaded?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

Hey guys I have an older site that is coded in AS2(I can't get it to AS3 sorry)  I found this script online that allows for mouse scrolling.  It is in AS3 and I can't figure out what Event replaced in AS2.  I'm sure there are much better AS programmers than me that could tell me off the bat.  I'm just trying to get this converted to AS2.  If someone could point me to the documentation that would be helpful.  Google'ng it didn't get me to far.

```
var verticalCenter:Number = stage.stageHeight / 2;
    var limit:Number = stage.stageHeight - content_mc.height; 
    var speed:Number = 0.1;
    var scrollY:Number = 0;

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scrollContent);

    function scrollContent(e:Event):void {
        scrollY = - speed * ( mouseY - verticalCenter ); 
        content_mc.y+= scrollY; 
        if (content_mc.y>0) { content_mc.y= 0;}
        else if (content_mc.y< limit) { content_mc.y= limit; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[google onEnterFrame](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=onenterframe%20as2&aq=2&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=onenterframe)